# Schema Evaluation with overwrite in Delta tables

Tags: pyspark, schema, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I am trying to include schema change for new type and dropped column in Delta tables.As per documentation

As per documentation:

```
df3
  .write
  .format("delta")
  .mode("overwrite")
  .option("mergeSchema", "true")
  .save(deltapath)
```

This way I loose old data. Is there anyway to keep olddata before overwriting with new schema apart from taking backup.
I have posted same query in databricks forum,link for your reference:
https://community.databricks.com/s/question/0D58Y00009WjZllSAF/what-is-the-best-way-to-take-care-of-drop-and-rename-a-column-in-schema-evaluation

One way is to create a backup of file before overwriting it.But I want to know what is best way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command you shared won't delete the existing data and it should still be queryable.

For example:

1. Create a table with 5 rows

   `spark.range(5).write.format("delta").save("/tmp/table")`
2. Overwrite with a new column & `mergeSchema` option

   ```
   spark.range(5)
   .withColumn("data", lit("data"))
   .write.format("delta")
   .mode("overwrite")
   .option("mergeSchema","true")
   .save("/tmp/table")
   ```
3. Query original data

   `` SELECT * FROM delta.`/tmp/table` VERSION AS OF 0 ``

   ```
   +---+
   | id|
   +---+
   |  0|
   |  1|
   |  2|
   |  3|
   |  4|
   +---+
   ```
4. Query new/current state

   `` SELECT * FROM delta.`/tmp/table` VERSION AS OF 1 ``

   ```
   +---+----+
   | id|data|
   +---+----+
   |  0|data|
   |  1|data|
   |  2|data|
   |  3|data|
   |  4|data|
   +---+----+
   ```